# Управленние процессами и потоками. Каналы. (операционные системы)

Tags: c, c++

Срочно нужно решить две задачки на языке С до 17.04. Я представления не имею, как это делать.

1) Написать программу "Пинг-Понг". Дано два потока. Первый генерирует случайным образом число от 0 до 10, посылает это число второму потоку. Второй поток плюсует двойку к данному числу и возвращает первому потоку. Первый плюсует тройку и возвращает второму потоку. Работа завершается, если число больше 100 Решить с помощью канала.

2) Дано целочисленный файл FILE_TO_SORT.DAT размером 5 GB. Отсортировать файл. Предложить оптимальное решение для 2-х ядерного ПК с Windows 7 (32 bit).

Буду очень благодарна!

Вот что есть пока:
`int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
HANDLE rpipe, wpipe;
STARTUPINFO si = {0}; PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, TRUE};
CreatePipe(&rpipe, &wpipe, &sa, 0);
si.hStdOutput = wpipe;
si.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
si.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
CreateProcess(NULL, _T("cmd /c dir"), NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
CloseHandle(wpipe);
CloseHandle(rpipe);
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
return 0;
}`

Comment: @Rolana, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Эх, стюденты. 
По поводу второго вопроса: посмотрите сортировку вставками.

Answer (score 1):

По второму вопросу заковырка как раз в том, что 32-бит система не может адресовать 5 гигобайт. Однако, ничто не мешает читать файл последовательно.

Решение в использовании *внешней* сортировки.

Очевидно, что надо открыть файл в 2-х потоках. Один будет читать первые 2.5 GB, а второй оставшуюся часть. Думаю, что каждый должен прочесть разумную часть  своей части файла (скажем, 0.5GB), рассортировать (qsort) в памяти и записать во временный файл. Получится 10 таких файлов (отсортированных).

Затем их просто надо объединить многопутевым слиянием, записывая результат в  FILE_TO_SORT.DAT.